# How to get Properties from an EObject, similiar to the Properties View

Tags: eclipse, properties, eclipse-rcp, ecore

i have an EObject and want to get all the Properties from it. I tryed to get all Structural Features:

```
myEObject.eClass().getEAllStructuralFeatures()
```

but i get too many Properties i do not want like the object ID.

With

```
myEObject.eClass().getEStructuralFeatures()
```

there are missing some that are displayed in the Properties View.

So how can i get the same List of Properties from an EObject like the Properties View does?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just use the first option and filter out the ones you don't want (like object id) from being displayed. It's probably the easiest way.

If it must absolutely be the same as the list that is displayed in the properties view, the safest bet is to find the code used to populate the properties view and reuse it.